# Invalid distance too far back zlib nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, zlib

I'm trying to compress and decompress the contents of a HTML file using [zlib](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html), to be able to send it over a post request to my database. I've got this code here, for example.

```
const { deflate, unzip } = require('zlib');
const input = '.................................';
deflate(input, (err, buffer) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('An error occurred:', err);
    process.exitCode = 1;
  }
  console.log(buffer.toString('base64'));
});

const buffer = Buffer.from('eJzT0yMAAGTvBe8=', 'base64');
unzip(buffer, (err, buffer) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('An error occurred:', err);
    process.exitCode = 1;
  }
  console.log(buffer.toString());
});
```

This is from NodeJS's official website, and it seems to work. It can compress and decompress the variable `input`. When I try to use this with my own variable, containing the HTML, deflating it worked; however, inflating it back into a string throws the error

```
(node:1353) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: invalid distance too far back
    at Zlib.zlibOnError [as onerror] (zlib.js:182:17)
    at processChunkSync (zlib.js:431:12)
    at zlibBufferSync (zlib.js:168:12)
    at Object.syncBufferWrapper [as unzipSync] (zlib.js:766:14)
    at inflateString (/home/runner/woc-bot/functions.js:62:36)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:1353) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1353) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I think this means that the encoded string that my database returns is corrupted, so I tried to just send a simple encoded string to the database, fetch it back, and then inflate it again.

```
const { deflate} = require('zlib');

const input = 'Hellow worldw';
deflate(input, (err, buffer) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('An error occurred:', err);
    process.exitCode = 1;
  }
  console.log(buffer.toString('base64'));
});
```

I get `eJzzSM3JyS9XKM8vykkpBwAjDAUr`, so I send this to the database, and get it back. I unzip it, and it returns `hellow worldw`

I'm really not sure what's happening, I'm using Repl.it's database (plz dont judge me) and this has been killing me for the past two days.

Comment: You ever get to the bottom of this? I'm experiencing the same problem; works with one string, not with another. I'm running it on JSON strings and the only difference seems to be the length. The bigger string throws the error.

Comment: nope i gave up a long time ago

Comment: Haha, fair enough. I almost did. So for me (in case anyone comes across this like me), it was a user error (classic). I was passing data around using URLSeachParams and I didn't notice that my browser was replacing spaces with the `+` symbol. Silly in the end.